# Yaml syntax error : service myphpadmin must be a mapping not a string yaml

Tags: yaml

```
wordpress:
 image: wordpress
 links:
 depends_on:
   - wordpress_db:mysql
 ports:
   - "8080:80"
wordpress_db:
 image: mariadb
 environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:edureka
phpmyadmin:
 image: corbinu/docker -phpmyadmin
 links:
 depends_on:
   - wordpress_db:mysql
 ports:
   - "8181:80"
  environment:
       MYSQL_USERNAME:root
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:edureka
```

Comment: sry guys not able to copy it in the correct formatt

Comment: adding 4 spaces at the beginning of a line will make it into a code block. Also, your question should include an *actual question* not just code: tell us what you are having issues with specificaly and clearly.

Comment: Add some code for people to understand the problem better

Comment: If you are getting YAML syntax errors, it's crucial to provide the exact YAML input. Please edit your post